# ASP.NET bind single instance data

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have a data class that I want to show in a list on one page and also alone in another page. I know how to do the first:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ctrl" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Here's the name: <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On the other page, I want to show exactly one instance, and I want to reuse the item template. Is there a control that I can bind to a single instance of this class, instead of a list which contains a single element?

Comment: What if you pass the value in query sting and then assign that value to label in second page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same `Repeater` but with a `DataSource` of on specific record/instance.

You can also use `FormView` control.

The [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295401%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx) control gives you the ability to work with a single record from a data source. The FormView control does not specify a pre-defined layout for displaying the record. Instead, you create a template containing controls to display individual fields from the record. For information about programming the FormView control, see [FormView Class](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=68438) in the MSDN library.

Comment: Except it seems crazy to use a repeater when there's only one data instance. And by the way, I tried, you can't set the DataSource to any object.

Comment: Define crazy !! It is like a loop with a single round.

Comment: I believe craziness is to develop a control that provide you with the ability to define an item template and bind it to a data source of a single item ...

Comment: No, craziness is that there's no such control already and I have to use a repeater and put my single item into a list :)

Comment: I know. But in my case, it's not a collection, it's a single item.

Comment: I am just saying: Don't feel wierd to use a Repeater with a DataSource of one item.

Comment: @fejesjoco: You can use `FormView` control.